# How to register a free "myblog.wordpress.com" blog

Tags: wordpress.com

I already have a blog - let's call it `foo.wordpress.com`.

I want to create a new, separate blog, called `foo-health.wordpress.com`.

I went to `https://wordpress.com/home/foo.wordpress.com`. Clicked "Switch site". Clicked "Add new site". Clicked "Start Now". I was redirected to a "Let's get your site a domain!" page. I want to skip this step, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Is it?

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention:

> ...I want to create a new, separate blog, called `foo-health.wordpress.com`
>
> ...I was redirected to a "Let's get your site a domain!" page. I want to skip this step, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Is it?

**No it is not.**

First of all you should be aware that your site/domain `foo-health.wordpress.com` is a [subdomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain). The same is true for all sites under `wordpress.com` which is a [multisite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress#Multi-user_and_multi-blogging).

You want to register a **new** site. This new site needs a name.
You want this new site to be called `foo-health.wordpress.com`.
You want this new site to have the domain name `foo-health.wordpress.com`.
You want the domain of this new site to be `foo-health.wordpress.com`.
So, `wordpress.com` says: *"Let's get your site a domain!"*

This happens because although you already own the domain/subdomain `foo.wordpress.com`, someone else may have already registered the subdomain `foo-health.wordpress.com` in which case will not be available.

Also, you should understand that **your** domain/site-name `foo-health.wordpress.com` is a subdomain of `wordpress.com` while `health.foo.wordpress.com` would be a subdomain of your `foo.wordpress.com` and at the same time a sub-subdomain of `wordpress.com`.
Unfortunately you are not allowed to create sub-subdomains in `wordpress.com`

In any case, just click next. It will all be clarified and if the name is available you will be the proud owner of `foo-health.wordpress.com`.

*(I hope my answer untangled this naming thread for you)*

Comment: Thank you. "In any case, just click next." - I don't see a "next" button

Comment: Ok, just noticed that the first line of the long list of available domains says "foohealth.wordpress.com". Great, so that's solved :) . Well, it doesn't respect my wish for a hyphen in the domain, but I can live with that :) Thanks again.

Comment: *"Well, it doesn't respect my wish for a hyphen in the domain..."*. It is taken then. No big deal. It is more about the content these days than just the name. Glad we solved it. :)